# Aws instance port refuse connection even its opened in security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to open port 8081 on AWS instance 
I modify the security group to all everyone connect to this port but when I tried to connect it give me service

```
refused to connect
```

did I miss something

Update I attached a screenshot of security groups 
[image]

Comment: Is there anything listening on that port?

Comment: yes wildfly server , I used https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check port but it show to me its closed

Comment: Are you sure it's listening on the external ip interface?

Comment: yea I am sure , acutually this was working till I tried add 443 port everything is messed up

Comment: If everything was accessible, you only changed the config and now it's not - how it's aws ec2 to blame? Revert the config, if it's okay again - you're doing something wrong with the application configuration.

Comment: I updated my question, I revert all changes and as you can see this port is opened, or the wildFly stop listening to this port

Comment: You said it was working before, but I would check if the machine has internet access (gateway to outside). Also I would check any existing rules if it is using iptables: `iptables -L`

Comment: which machine you mean its AWS instance . its sure connect to internet , I dont know what you mean by existing rules if it is using iptables: iptables -L any reference to read more about it

Comment: "or the wildFly stop listening to this port" --- that's why I asked you to **double check it** otherwise we're wasting time 

Answer (score 1):

If you have a public IP assigned to your EC2 instance and you hve opened the port on the security group to be accessed form your IP/anywhere then you need to check whether wildfly public interface is configured to listen on any IP. By default wildfly only listens to the localhost IP i.e. 127.0.0.1. Depending on the mode you are running the wildfly in for example standalone then you should find this config

```
<interface name="public">  
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>  
 </interface>
```

and replace it with

```
<interface name="public">  
        <any-address/> 
 </interface>
```

or

```
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
```

Comment: here what I find 
 <interface name="public">
            <any-ipv4-address/>
        </interface>

Comment: so does it work? What endpoint are you hitting? If it is listening on the port and is opened to be accessed publicly using a public IP/DN then it should work. Hope you have not messed up the listener port?

Comment: I have touch the code I change some configuration on AWS trying to make our api listen to 443 , but everything goes down I tried back everything as it was but still not listening to port 8081

Comment: maybe your war file is not deployed properly. Are you able to access the admin portl?

Comment: we dont have pem file is there anyway I can gain access

Comment: if you don't have the pem file, you can't ssh.

Comment: is there any way to connect to instance except ssh

Comment: You have completely changed the initial question and my answer is not valid anymore as it was focussed on the jboss. Now you are asking about normal ssh without pem key, which is not possible. The other way is to create an image of your instance and create a new instance with the image and a new pem file. Then you will be able to ssh to that instance, which is a replica.

Comment: yea I know I took you to anther direction sorry, I tried to open all ports for testing even so it's not working, I am also connected to SSh and see the deployed file there .war I am really dont what to do